# Fill prompt content using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have created a prompt. All the structure of the prompt is made using `HTML`.

I want to fill all the content in the `html` from `json` file.

The header, content and footer data will be fetched from `json` file.

Here in the code I have added the content in header, middle body and footer directly...I want that content to be fetched from `json` file.

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            .container{width:500px; height:100%;border:1px solid grey;margin:20px;position:relative;}
            .header{background-color:#00CDCD;height:50px;border:1px solid white;}
            h1{margin-top:0;color:#ffffff;margin:5px 12px;}
            .footer{background-color: #cecece; bottom: 0; height: 50px; left: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%;text-align:center;} 
            button{margin-top:12px;}
            .content{height:auto;position:absolute;overflow:auto;margin:10px;}
        </style>

        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <button>Button 1</button>
                <button>Button 2</button>
                <button>button 3</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also the height of the prompt is stretching long. Any help?

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not that familier with json and have not used it...so could not start to work on that. I am not finding a way to create the objects in json file

Comment: How to create object in json file

Answer (score 0):

1)Make a json call

```
$.ajax({
        url: link,
        success: function (result) {
            $('.content').html(result);// Append the html to the div
        }
    });
```

2) Make sure you give id's to the div and bind the html to that id
like #contenttab

```
 $('#contenttab').html(result);
```

3) usually json should return a partial view or some html page

Comment: How would be the json file?

Answer (score 0):

initially work with the mocked data, say make a file which contains the json data and work on that

```
$.ajax({
   url: window.localhost?localfileURl:actualUrl
   success: function(){
     $(".content").html(result);
   }
})
```

make the localhost to true when you are working in dev

Comment: How to make a json file with objects here

Comment: store jsonObject in a file with .json extenstion

Comment: what the JSON file will contain?

Comment: the file will contain json object